# Retrieve the previously populated values and selection after page refresh in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a jsp page which contains a dialog box. The dialog box has radio buttons and also a drop-down list and 2 buttons. Checking the radio boxes some actions are performed. On that action the drop-down list is populated. Onselecting the items in drop down a table is populated in the same dialog box. There is a refresh button which calls the dialog box function so that all values in the dropdown list are deleted and even the table. But I need the following

- Onclick of Refresh button I need to retrieve the previously populated values as it is in the drop down.
- Onclick of Refresh button the radio button which was previously checked should be retrieved.

**myjsp.jsp**

```
<input type="radio" class="radioButton" value="Display all" checked onclick="fnCheck();"> Display All

<input type="radio" class="radioButton" value="Display Divisions" onclick="fnCheck();"> Display Divisions 


<input type="radio" class="radioButton" value="Display Data" onclick="fnCheck();"> Display Data 
<select class="convoy_list">
<option>Values</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="testbtn" value="Test" onclick="fnClickTest();" >
<input type="button" id="ok" value="OK" onclick="fnOK();" >
<input type="button" id="Refresh" value="Refresh" onclick="fnDisplay();" >
```

By default the radio button "Display All" is checked. Rest all buttons are disabled. Onchecking the radio button "Display Data" the drop down list, the "Test" buttons are enabled. Some actions are performed onclick of Test button and drop down is populated. And onselecting items from drop down table is populated in the same dialog box.

Onclick of Refresh button I need to retrieve the previously stored values and also retrieve the radio button which was checked previously and not the default radio button.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html),

When the use clicks on button then save the data and check if data found in localStorage then show it.

For egs,

```
$(function(){
    $('.radioButton').on('click',function(){
       // your code
       // now set the radio value in localstorage
       localStorage.setItem('defaultRadio',this.value);
    });
    if(localStorage.getItem('defaultRadio')){ // check that defaultRadio is set or not
        // if it is set then trigger a click on that radio by its value
        $('input[value="'+localStorage.getItem('defaultRadio')+'"]').click();
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/xm2kot6m/)

Comment: will this save all the values associated with the radio button? or only the radio button value?

Comment: only the button value, I show only an example how to use it? You can store json data in a variable and show it as required

Comment: i actually want to retrieve the previosuly checked radio button onclick of Refresh

Comment: When i try doing : 'localStorage.setItem("def",this.value);' and try to alert this i get value as undefined. Is the browser not supporting?

Comment: Its `localStorage.setItem` not `local.setItem`

Comment: Sorry typing mistake. Yes still it is undefined

Comment: See my updated answer and a demo for localstorage on http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/xm2kot6m/

Comment: Yes sir. It works great with radio buttons. Solved that issue. But the same way how do I retrieve the drop-down list even after refresh?

Comment: Store the dropdown values in form of json and get it in the same way as radio element.

Comment: So i should use JSON.stringify(mydropdwnarray) for my drop-down list array?

Comment: Yes and when you need to use it then use `jQuery.parseJSON()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59333/discussion-between-user3201640-and-rohan-kumar).

Comment: I tried it works only for the last item in the array :(